# CSS Responsive - change order of div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```css
#div1 {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {

     #div1 {
          position: absolute;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    
<body>

<div id="div1">
  <h1>Box 1</h1>   
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>   
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is their a way I can change the orders of divs based on the type of device I am browsing my site on? I am attempting to create a responsive design. I created this very simple sample which essentially has 3 divs. They are in order 1, 2,3 on a desktop. I added media queries in my css to handle mobile devices. I want the order to change from 2,1,3. I am sure there must be a way to accomplish this with css only, but I am not familiar enough with it. Any ideas? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<style>
    #div1 {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {

     #div1 {
          position: absolute;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }


    }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="div1">
  <h1>Box 1</h1>   
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>   
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can try to use Flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/): take a look at the order property.

Comment: Thanks, the order property looks like what I need however it doesn't appear to support IE 9 which i may need

Comment: I'm afraid that if you need to support IE9, the best thing to do is use some javascript.

Comment: Another possibility is to use absolute positions, but I guess this will not be a good solution. With relative positioning, maybe if you can try changing the float from the divs (left, right, none), but I really don't know if it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` to display the elements and change the order using `order`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<style>
    #div1 {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
  body{
    display:flex;/*
    flex-direcion:row;*/
    }
      #div2{
       order:-1;
        }

     #div1 {/*
     position: absolute;*/
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {/*
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;*/
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

    }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="div1">
  <h1>Box 1</h1>   
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>   
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Method 2:- (Works in all browser)**

Add  hidden div which will show only when `max-width:400px` and hide the original div. it will work even IE-9 and in lower versions too

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<style>
    #div1, #div1-alter {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
    #div1-alter{
        display:none;
    }

    #div2 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {

      #div2{
       order:-1;
        }

     #div1, #div1-alter {/*
     position: absolute;*/
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }

    #div2 {/*
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;*/
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
          color: white;
    }

      #div3 {
         position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
          color: white;
    }
    #div1{
        display:none;
    }
    #div1-alter{
        display:inherit;
    }
    }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="div1">
  <h1>Box 1</h1>   
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>   
</div>
<div id="div1-alter">
  <h1>Box 1</h1>   
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the flexbox approach is exactly what I need, however I need to be able to accommodate older browsers. I do hate having to show and hide divs based on screen size but I may have no choice.

Comment: Yaah. Otherwise you can do with javascript. if you are concerning about the old browsers with only css then thats the best working thing.  
Accept and upvote if it really helps. so that it would be helpful to find solution for someone like you.